# Monit alert/exec when host is back to normal

Tags: monitoring, uptime, monit

I use **Monit** to quick check uptime of Elasticsearch service.

Here is my configuration:

```
check host [Elasticsearch]-test with address 1.2.3.4
    if failed
        port 9200
        protocol http
    then exec "/alerting/monit2telegram/monit2telegram.sh"
```

It means: when monit cannot do a http request to port 9200, then receive a notification to telegram. It works perfectly when my elastic is down.

But when **host is back to normal**, how can i configure monit that push alert/exec to remind?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
check host [Elasticsearch]-test with address 1.2.3.4
    if failed
        port 9200
        protocol http
    then exec "/alerting/monit2telegram/monit2telegram.sh"
    else if succeeded then exec /alerting/monit2telegram/monit2telegram.sh"
```

It will exec again, when host is back to normal.